# Pramp Reverse sentence interview question in C#

Tags: c#

This is taken from pramp site, I am trying to follow their psudo code which is an answer to the following question.

**

> You are given an array of characters arr that consists of sequences of
>   characters separated by space characters. Each space-delimited
>   sequence of characters defines a word. Implement a function
>   reverseWords that reverses the order of the words in the array in the
>   most efficient manner.

**

example:

```
    input:  arr = [ 'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', '  ',
                   'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', '  ',
                    'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e' ]

    output: [ 'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', '  ',
              'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', '  ',
              'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't' ]
```

here is my code. it works.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace StringQuestions
{

    [TestClass]
    public class ReverseSentanceTest
    {

    [TestMethod]
    public void ManyWordsTest()
    {
        char[] inputArray = {
            'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ',
            'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' ',
            'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e'
        };
        char[] expectedOutputArr = {'p', 'r', 'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ',
      'm', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' ',
      'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't'};
        char[] outputArr = ReserverseSentence(inputArray);

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedOutputArr, outputArr);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OneWordTest()
    {
        char[] inputArray = {
            'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', 
        };
        char[] expectedOutputArr = {

      'p', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't'};
        char[] outputArr = ReserverseSentence(inputArray);

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedOutputArr, outputArr);
    }

        public char[] ReserverseSentence(char[] inputArr)
        {
            if (inputArr == null || inputArr.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("array is empty");
            }
            MirrorArray(inputArr, 0, inputArr.Length-1);
            int indexStart = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.Length; i++)
            {
                //end of a word in the middle of the sentence
                if (inputArr[i] == ' ')
                {
                    MirrorArray(inputArr, indexStart, i - 1);
                    indexStart = i+1; //skip the white space and start from the letter after
                }
                else if (i == inputArr.Length - 1)
                {
                    MirrorArray(inputArr, indexStart, i); 
                }
            }
            return inputArr;
        }

        private void MirrorArray(char[] inputArr, int start, int end)
        {
            while (start < end)
            {
                var temp = inputArr[start];
                inputArr[start] = inputArr[end];
                inputArr[end] = temp;
                start++;
                end--;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

however I think I missed a corner case. their pseudo code has 3 if/else branches. I just init my word start as an integer where they use something like `nullable<int>`.

```
function reverseWords(arr):
    # reverse all characters:
    n = arr.length
    mirrorReverse(arr, 0, n-1)

    # reverse each word:
    wordStart = null
    for i from 0 to n-1:
        if (arr[i] == ' '):
            if (wordStart != null):
                mirrorReverse(arr, wordStart, i-1)
                wordStart = null
        else if (i == n-1):
            if (wordStart != null):
                mirrorReverse(arr, wordStart, i)
        else:
            if (wordStart == null):
                wordStart = i

    return arr


# helper function - reverses the order of items in arr
# please note that this is language dependent:
# if are arrays sent by value, reversing should be done in place

function mirrorReverse(arr, start, end):
    tmp = null
    while (start < end):
        tmp = arr[start]
        arr[start] = arr[end]
        arr[end] = tmp
        start++
        end--
```

Can you please explain if I am missing some corner case? and give an example. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `indexStart` to one letter after the space in the following code:

```
if (inputArr[i] == ' ')
{
    MirrorArray(inputArr, indexStart, i - 1);
    indexStart = i+1; //skip the white space and start from the letter after
}
```

Rather than setting the `indexStart` to an uninitialised variable then checking if the variable is uninitialised  and then initialising it with the position in the array of the next new word, like so:

```
wordStart = null
for i from 0 to n-1:
    if (arr[i] == ' '):
        if (wordStart != null):
            mirrorReverse(arr, wordStart, i-1)
            wordStart = null
```

What you could do is set `indexStart` to `-1` and then in your loop check if the value of `indexStart` is `-1` and use this as an indication that you have started a new word and can record the index within the array (`arr`). You could do it like this:

```
int indexStart = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.Length; i++)
{
   //end of a word in the middle of the sentence
   if (inputArr[i] == ' ')
   {
      MirrorArray(inputArr, indexStart, i - 1);
      indexStart = -1; //ready to record next index of new word
   }
   else if (i == inputArr.Length - 1)
   {
      MirrorArray(inputArr, indexStart, i); 
   }
   else
   {
      if(indexStart < 0)
            indexStart = i; //index of new word
   }
}
```

The key thing is setting `indexStart` to a value that you won't be set naturally inside the loop, like `-1`, or `null` if you want to use a nullable type like `int?` but then you'll have to perform a check for a value before you try access it to avoid `NullReferenceExceptions`, you are almost better using `-1`

Comment: Can someone format this. It's nearly impossible on mobile SO

Comment: but why do you even need this check?

Comment: You don't, what you have is what I would have went with myself. I don't see any benefit other than readability perhaps